# ¿Qué significa "etrai guán" para Nicolás Guillén?

Tags: poesía, cuba

En los versos *Tú no sabe inglé* escribe Nicolás Guillén de manera fonética.

Así,   «La americana te busca» se vuelve  «La mericana te buca», y  «one, two, three» es representado por «guan tu tri».

¿Alguien puede decirme (de ser posible con evidencia) qué significa «etrái guan»?

> Con tanto inglé que tú sabía,
>   Bito Manué,
>   con tanto inglé, no sabe ahora
>   desí ye.
>
> La mericana te buca,
>   y tú le tiene que huí:
>   tu inglé era de etrái guan,
>   de **etrái guan** y guan tu tri.
>
> Bito Manué, tú no sabe inglé,
>   tú no sabe inglé,
>   tú no sabe inglé.
>
> No te namore ma nunca.
>   Bito Manué,
>   si no sabe inglé,
>   si no sabe inglé.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quizás signifique **strike one**, una jugada de beisbol que se marca cuando un bateador falla el golpe. Tres strikes consecutivos suponen la expulsión del bateador. Al menos eso es lo que he aprendido viendo películas americanas. En España no está muy extendido este deporte.

Dado que Nicolás Guillén era cubano y el beisbol es uno de los deportes nacionales de la isla caribeña, hay posibilidades de que esta sea la interpretación adecuada.

Comment: +1 No puede ser otra cosa.

Answer (score 2):

> Below is an extract from Guillén’s well-known poem ‘Tu no sabe inglé’, translated by Hughes as ‘You don’t speak no English’. Hughes’s translation used the African American vernacular to reproduce Guillén’s experimentation with the Cuban *criollo* (Creole) dialect in his poetry:
>
> > All dat English you used to know,
> >
> > Li’l Manuel,
> >
> > all dat English, now can’t even
> >
> > say: *Yes*.
> >
> > ‘Merican gal comes lookin’ fo’ you
> >
> > an’ you jes’ runs away
> >
> > Yo’ English is jes’ ***strike one***!
> >
> > ***strike one*** and *one-two-three*.
>
> - Langston Hughes’s translation, published in *Cuba Libre* (1948)

Source: [Langston Hughes translates Nicolás Guillén](https://blogs.bl.uk/americas/2016/03/langston-hughes-translates-nicolas-guillen-.html)